# Installing Pygame - Registry wont show

Tags: python, pygame

I have a problem when trying to install Pygame. My Python is installed under Program Files in the C drive (C:\Program Files\Python). My registry wont show, and I have no idea what I shall do. Should it go under site-packages or what? Believe me, I've been searching around for ages in order to solve this. Please come with specific steps on what I shall do. Sorry, I'm new to this (as you can see). Correct me if I use registry wrong :)

[image]

Comment: Please use [imgur](http://imgur.com/) to upload your image, and then post a link to it here.

Comment: http://imgur.com/upqwWy0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First visit [here](http://www.pygame.org/install.html).
Be sure that you have installed numpy properly and then check once more that you have downloaded the proper pygame binary for your specific OS (x32, x64).

If everything of the above fails, un-install python and reinstall it (again using the proper version).

I had some similar issues with PIL and after reinstalling python it fixed.

For  picture  issue: You can upload it to your dropbox or google drive and share here the link.

Edit: Be  sure that python is in the environment variables path of  windows

edit2: which version of python do you use. Python 2.x has some incoherences with python 3.x so check that too.

Comment: Is it any specific place I should install Python in the first place? Can I for example make a Python folder manually in Program Files and install Python there?

Comment: @Andreas Amudsen i am not sure this has to do with that. i guess you have a different version of pygame than you should,  according to your python version

Comment: you can find here: [https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads] different pygame versions

Comment: and for windows `python -V` in cmd will print the currentversion of python

Comment: @Andreas Amundsen this one [https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads] is the correct link the other one is dead. i also noticed from the picture that you want  python 3.3 so if that's the case upgrade. oh and accept my answer if  you find it useful at all.

Comment: Thanks for reply! OK, so I checked my py version and it was 3.3.3. I downloaded the second download from the top at Pygame Bitbucket site. Then I tried to install numpy from here (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy). I tried both downloads, where I guess you are supposed to launch setup.py. When I did so there was a flash of a cmd windows with some text, that went away with the cmd window. Any suggestions what I should do? :)

Comment: try the  unofficial binaries in this site: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy. Think about going OS rather than windows via a Virtual Machine, just to do your job if you don't like Linux. Things there are so simple..

Comment: One thing first about that enviroment variable (I'm not too good at that). Shall I make a System Variable called Python and the variable value shall be the py directory? @KapelNick

Comment: It's wierd beacause numpy doesen't seem to find Py 3.3 either

Comment: @AndreasAmundsen read the docs! [http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html] yes the idea is to  include python into the path giving as value the python bin

Comment: Ok, lets take it from the start.. I installed AMD64 python, which now is located in C:\Python33. Then I wrote python -v in cmd, which listed Python 3.3.3 64 Bit (AMD64). Then I launched numpy again with that blue background installer thingy. Still, it said python 3.3 could not be found

Comment: I finally managed to install Numpy (reinstalled Python once again..). Ima try install pygame now

Comment: @AndreasAmundsen Well done then you are already making progress. remember to take it easy though.. tomorrow its a new and  fresh day

Comment: Thanks for the help and patience so far! When I do `import pygame` this error shows `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

Comment: @AndreasAmundsen yes you are close! now add the pygame binaries path to the windows env. variable and maybe you ll have to restart  win.  i think that should be it

Comment: I did it :D I finally did it! Just installed a new ver of pygame, and it worked! Thanks for the help man! You'll hear from me if I have any other issues ;)

Comment: How do I do it :P Sorry, this is my secondth visit to this site